# Fill new table with count and 2 variables

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I’m trying to get a new table filled with a calculation from a query (or multiple)

I have a table tomtom with the following columns:
tripid
drivername
start_time
end_time (date and time)
start_postext
end_postext

I’m trying to create a table named woperdayperengineer with the following columns:
id
drivername
end_time  (1 day per engineer)
woperday

I want it to make a record for every engineer with the number of trips he had to a specific place (which can be found in tomtom.end_postext).

I made a query for this:

```
SELECT Count(tomtom.tripid) AS NumberOfTripsToASite
FROM tomtom
WHERE tomtom.end_time BETWEEN #11/12/2013# AND #11/13/2013#
AND tomtom.drivername = "John Johnson"
AND 
(
tomtom.end_postext Like "*S0*" 
Or tomtom.end_postext Like "*S1*"
Or tomtom.end_postext Like "*S2*"
Or tomtom.end_postext Like "*S3*" 
Or tomtom.end_postext Like "*S4*" 
Or tomtom.end_postext Like "*S5*"
Or tomtom.end_postext Like "*S6*" 
Or tomtom.end_postext Like "*S7*" 
Or tomtom.end_postext Like "*S8*" 
Or tomtom.end_postext Like "*S9*" 
Or tomtom.end_postext Like "*K0*" 
Or tomtom.end_postext Like "*K1*" 
Or tomtom.end_postext Like "*K2*" 
Or tomtom.end_postext Like "*K3*" 
Or tomtom.end_postext Like "*K3*" 
Or tomtom.end_postext Like "*K4*" 
Or tomtom.end_postext Like "*K5*" 
Or tomtom.end_postext Like "*K6*" 
Or tomtom.end_postext Like "*K7*" 
Or tomtom.end_postext Like "*K8*" 
Or tomtom.end_postext Like "*K9*"
) 
And tomtom.end_postext Not Like "*Shurgard*";
```

The result gives the number of trips that John Johnson made on 11/12/2013.

I want this automated so it will fill table woperdayperengineer automatically.

I did make a query to get a list of dates:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DateValue(tomtom.end_time)
FROM tomtom;
```

And I did made a query to get a list of drivers:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (tomtom.drivername)
FROM tomtom;
```

Now how do I combine these into a query or vba script that fills the table automatically?

I would like to build in a check to make sure it does not enter dates that are already in the woperdayperengineer table.

All I have so far is the loop in VBA actually. I don’t know where to start. Does anyone have a hint or an example code?

I'm using Access 2007

**UPDATE AFTER FIRST 2 RESPONCES:**

Thanks a lot for the responses!
So far I have this (based on a combination of both your codes):

**Woperdayperengineer_append_qry:**

```
INSERT INTO woperdayperengineer
SELECT tomtom.drivername AS drivername,
Format (tomtom.end_time, "mm/dd/yyyy") AS end_time,
Count(tomtom.tripid) AS woperday
FROM tomtom
WHERE tomtom.end_time BETWEEN #11/12/2013# AND #11/13/2013#
AND tomtom.drivername = "John Johnson"
AND 
(
tomtom.end_postext Like "*S#*" 
Or tomtom.end_postext Like "*K#*" 
) 
And tomtom.end_postext Not Like "*Shurgard*"
GROUP BY
tomtom.drivername,
Format (tomtom.end_time, "mm/dd/yyyy");
```

**Form3 with button Command0:**

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()
    Dim dbb As Database
    Set dbb = CurrentDb
    Private Sub ButtonName_Click()
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    CurrentDb.Execute "woperdayperengineer_append_qry"
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
End Sub
```

When I press the button nothing happens.

Also I think it needs 1 more step before its fully automated. (I don’t mind if it get triggered automatically at the startup or if you have to press a button, off course fully automatic would be the nicest). The date part (BETWEEN #11/12/2013# AND #11/13/2013#) should automaticly pick the next date that an engineer worked.  When all trips from the engineer are done, it should pick the next engineer (drivername) and generate a list of all the dates that he worked.

When the code is finished table woperdayperengineer should look like this:

```
drivername – end_time – woperday
John Johnson 11/12/2013 2
John Johnson 11/13/2013 3
John Johnson 11/14/2013 5
Jack Jackson 11/12/2013 1
Jack Jackson 11/13/2013 4
Jack Jackson 11/14/2013 5
```

The tomtom data looks like this (made up data):

```
tripid - drivername - start_time - end_time - start_postext - end_postext (and more)
123144 - John Johnson - 11/12/2013 1:45:16 PM - 11/12/2013 2:45:16 PM - Kalverstreet, Amsterdam - Longstreet 69, Rotterdam, K0347
123145 - John Johnson - 11/12/2013 3:49:36 PM - 11/12/2013 4:49:36 PM - Coolsingel, Rotterdam, S2345 - Damstreet, Amsterdam, S3345
123146 - Jack Jackson - 11/12/2013 10:49:36 AM - 11/12/2013 1:49:37 PM - Herenstreet, Den Haag - Neudestreet, Utrecht, K8765
```

You mentioned “change/remove date/name criteria as you desire”, but I don’t know how.

Again thanks for all the help so far.

Comment: Do you want to "automate" this to grab all info at once?  Or do you want to automate this to update daily/weekly/monthly etc as time goes by?  It sounds like you could use an append query...

Comment: Thx! I want to make the table from all the tomtom data so far. Then I want a possibility to update it when I import new data to the database. I'm thinking of updating the tomtom table dayly or weekly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unverified since I don't have your tables, but this should work:

(change/remove date/name criteria as you desire)

```
INSERT INTO woperdayperengineer
SELECT
Count(tomtom.tripid) AS ID,
tomtom.drivername AS Drivername,
Format (tomtom.end_time, "mm/dd/yyyy") AS End_time
FROM tomtom
WHERE tomtom.end_time BETWEEN #11/12/2013# AND #11/13/2013#
AND tomtom.drivername = "John Johnson"
AND 
(
tomtom.end_postext Like "*S0*" 
Or tomtom.end_postext Like "*S1*"
Or tomtom.end_postext Like "*S2*"
Or tomtom.end_postext Like "*S3*" 
Or tomtom.end_postext Like "*S4*" 
Or tomtom.end_postext Like "*S5*"
Or tomtom.end_postext Like "*S6*" 
Or tomtom.end_postext Like "*S7*" 
Or tomtom.end_postext Like "*S8*" 
Or tomtom.end_postext Like "*S9*" 
Or tomtom.end_postext Like "*K0*" 
Or tomtom.end_postext Like "*K1*" 
Or tomtom.end_postext Like "*K2*" 
Or tomtom.end_postext Like "*K3*" 
Or tomtom.end_postext Like "*K3*" 
Or tomtom.end_postext Like "*K4*" 
Or tomtom.end_postext Like "*K5*" 
Or tomtom.end_postext Like "*K6*" 
Or tomtom.end_postext Like "*K7*" 
Or tomtom.end_postext Like "*K8*" 
Or tomtom.end_postext Like "*K9*"
) 
And tomtom.end_postext Not Like "*Shurgard*"
GROUP BY
tomtom.drivername,
Format (tomtom.end_time, "mm/dd/yyyy");
```

Save this as whatever you like, say `woperdayperengineer_append_qry`.  Make `Drivername` and `End_time` the primary keys for the `woperdayperengineer` table so you'll never have duplicate records (i.e. more than one entry per driver per day).  Then make a form with a button and assign the following VBA (where "ButtonName" is to be replaced with whatever your button is named):

```
Dim dbb As Database
Set dbb = CurrentDb
Private Sub ButtonName_Click()
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
CurrentDb.Execute "woperdayperengineer_append_qry"
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
End Sub
```

This will add all records from your query, while turning warnings off will allow it to only add new (unique) records without asking you about it.